# enable to access ajax request variable in controller in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

```
$("#shopname").keypress(function(){ $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "/admin_home/test/", data: {email:$(this).val()} , success: $('#subcategory_details').append('<%=@sub1%> ') }); });
controller

@sub1=params[:email]
```

server response on ajax request

> Started POST "/admin_home/test/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-04 15:40:56
>   +0530 Processing by AdminHomeController#test as / Parameters: {"email"=>"jnkn"} ←[1m←[35mMasterusers Load (1.0ms)←[0m select * from
>   product_sub_category_1 wh ere product_category_id=1 Rendered
>   admin_home/test.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)

Answer (score 0):

In your request you only have the email parameter and you already know how to access it:

```
email = params[:email]
```

you can use it as is in your controller.